# Use Lucene.Net IndexReader in the right way

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

In one of my `WCF` solutions, the user can search on the Lucene index. Im looking to get input about the approach.

Can I improve this code in a better way?

```
public class ViewData
{            
        public static IndexReader indexReader
        {
            get
            {  
                return IndexReader.Open(FSDirectory.Open("path"), true);
            }
            private set { indexReader = value; }
        }
        public static IndexSearcher indexSearcher { get; set; }
}
```

To consume

```
using (indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader))
{
    // run the search etc
}
```

This means the `IndexReader` is never closed when the searcher is opened this way.

But if I do like below.

```
using (indexReader)
using (indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader))
{
        // run the search etc
}
```

But this means the reader is always closed and re-opened? Can I skip `using(indexReader)` and leave it open (isnt that bad practice since the `IndexReader` is `Disposable`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reuse both the IndexReader and IndexSearcher instances for several requests. They are thread-safe and can serve several requests simultaneously. There's no need to close or dispose of your readers and searches, garbage collection will handle that automatically. In fact, it will be hard to do if you're reusing the instances over several requests since you do not know if someone is using it at the same time.

Comment: Tested and it runs perfect. Tack broshan!

Answer (score 1):

In our application we sort of avoid the problem by using the constructor overload of  `IndexSearcher` that accepts a Lucene Directory path.

The code looks something like this:

```
using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(_luceneSearchPath.GetActiveIndexPath()))))
{
    // run the search etc
}
```

The documentation for the constructor accepting an IndexReader says that "**If the IndexReader was supplied implicitly by specifying a directory, then the IndexReader gets closed.**". So I would say closing the IndexReader is the right thing to do.

Performance while searching is good in our app, and there have been no problems with memory leaks.